# Remmina redraws once per second - how to stop it?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, vnc, redraw

I installed [Remmina 1.2.0-rcgit.11 (git n/a)](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) remote desktop client on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, to connect to a Windows 8.1 Basic machine running [tightVNC Server 2.7.10](http://www.tightvnc.com/?f=sa) . When I first connected, the display of the Windows machine on Ubuntu was very smooth (just a bit delayed - I had the two machines next to each other and could see the delay).

After a while mucking around with other things and rebooting both machines a few times the quality of the Windows display on Ubuntu had changed - there was an obvious redraw of the screen approximately once or twice every second. The whole display is blacked out then redraws from the top down in large blocks. This makes it very hard to view and interact with the displayed remote screen.

I presume I must have changed some setting in Remmina, and have looked at all the settings but can't work out what the problem is. Any suggestions for what to look at would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem didn't arise in the Remmina client. I got the same flashing redraw when using the vinagre client on Ubuntu.

The problem is associated with the tightVNC server running on Windows. I don't know if there was something specific about my Windows machine that made tightVNC Server unhappy, but presume there must be because nobody would use tightVNC Server if it always flashed the client screen.

I switched to realVNC server on the Windows machine and that solved the problem. I am still using the Remmina client on Ubuntu.